# TSQL for "Ignore databases were the state is not online"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a few custom jobs on a mirrored SQL Server 2005 and they fail from time to time because of automatic failover.

Is there some T-SQL code that I can write into my automated jobs or do I just have to remember to set failover so the job doesn't fail?

[image]

Comment: You can put IF statement in your TSQL code or can filter out databases from `sys.databases where state_desc=ONLINE`. You can also use GUI as shown above

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use [Ola's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) (and [Index maintenance  solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) as well). This is a well [applauded solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/organizations.html) that is smart enough to work with mirroring (in your case).

Maintenance plans are not bad, but when your environment grows, the limited flexibility and functionality that maintenance plans provide wont be sufficient.

For e.g Maintenance plans suffer from below drawbacks :

- There is no `CHECKSUM` option when taking backup of databases or there is no option of verifying backups using CHECKSUM.
- There is not much logic you can implement when dealing with index fragmentation and once you configure it, they run regardless if you **really** need a reorg or rebuild on your indexes... and many more :-)

To address your issue, you need to check `sys.databases where state_desc = 'ONLINE'` and adjust your scripts.

Also, you can have a [script](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/automated-job-activation-with-mirroring/) that detects failover and disables the jobs on secondary server.

**Gentle Note**: [Extended support for SQL Server 2005 ends on April 12, 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-and-end-of-service-pack-support-for-sql-server-2008-sp1/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you are asking but you can tell if a database is online by looking in [sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) at the `state_desc` column.

Possible values are:

- ONLINE
- RESTORING
- RECOVERING (SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016)
- RECOVERY_PENDING (SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016)
- SUSPECT
- EMERGENCY (SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016)
- OFFLINE (SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016)
- COPYING (Azure SQL Database)
- OFFLINE_SECONDARY (Azure SQL Database)

So in your case you probably want to run something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DBName AND state_desc = 'ONLINE')
    Your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for something like this, Minion Backup is actually going to be a much better solution.  It's not only Mirror aware, but it's also AG, and log shipping aware. You can do many things with it HA/DR wise that you can't do with other solutions.

For example, you can have it write to different locations when it's in different data centers and you can have it keep the settings in sync between different nodes of your AG or your mirror. This is handy when you change a backup setting on the live node and you forget to change it on the secondary node. Minion Backup will keep them in sync for you.

There are many many other options that make the solution much more complete than anything else, and there is a free version. Here's the download:

[Minion Backup](http://minionware.net/backup/)

There are also videos that show you how to use all the features and it's fully supported.

*Disclaimer: I am the [author](http://minionware.net/about-us/) of this product.*